# How do I setup a CloudFlare Origin Certificate in AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

When I try to import the Origin Certificate that CloudFlare provides into AWS Certificate Manager so I can use it with an ELB, ALB or NLB I find that it requires a key chain certificate that they didn't provide to me. Where can I get that?

Answer (score 6):

CloudFlare published the key chain certificates in their support article here:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-

Which Origin CA you use, depends on if you used their RCA or ECDSA cert creation. If you aren't sure which you used, run this command on the public cert, `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout|grep "Signature Algorithm"`

Cloudflare Origin CA — RSA Root

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Cloudflare Origin CA — ECC Root

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved the issue by just trial and error:

Get root CA from: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-

For example, in RSA format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Cloudflare Origin CA 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And you have your own Certificate as:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Your own
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now, you put them in to AWS certificate management console as the following:

**Certificate**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Your own
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Secret**

```
your secret
```

**Certificate Chain**, you need to combine your own certificate and cloudflare root CA, and notice the sequence matters!

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Cloudflare Origin CA 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Your own
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```